# Firefox calculates elements width differently in different computers

Tags: html, css

I encountered today a weird situation. I have issues in a Joomla website (http://boaz.simplem-test.tk) I have built, with the way that Firefox determines the width of `li` (list item) between different computers.
The problem there is with the top menu. the entire `ul.main.menu` width in one computer is calculated as 705px and in another computer as 722px. when I looked at the items width, in each one there is 1-2 pixels difference.
Both computers have the same version of Firefox (20.0.1), both run on the same OS (Windows 7).
Any ideas as to why this can happen?

Comment: There might be some difference... let's see. Screen resolution in both computers are equal?

Comment: Checked it just now, screen resolution is the same, 1366*768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening up the CSS source code, http://boaz.simplem-test.tk/templates/main_template/css/template.css , reveals no explicit settings for width in the 'main menu'.  As well, when I look at the page using Google Chrome's right-click 'Inspect Element' function ( in your case, due to a 'no-right-click' script, I had to access it using the Chrome Menu->Tools->Developer Tools ), the `li`s in the main menu report as `width:auto`.  Since this is the case, each menu item is automatically assigned a width according to the text contained in it, and the menu as a whole could be affected by this.  In the said console width of the whole menu is calculated as 705px, but I could not find where this was specified in the code.  But the crux of the problem seems to be the header `<div>`, which comes in at 975px, instead of 1000px, like the rest of the page.  You ought to specify `width="1000px"` for the header, and that might fix the problem. בהצלחה!